# ODBC Connection Setup in Java

Tags: java, odbc

I want to write a Java program that automates the work that the ODBC Data Source Administrator does in Windows.

That is, given an ODBC connection name and a path to the database on the hard drive, I want it to create the connection.

I really have no idea where to even begin with this.  I looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714177(VS.85).aspx) but it said it was for C and I don't think that's very helpful.  If anyone could point me in the right direction for this at all, I would appreciate it.

(I realize this question is REALLY vague, but that's all the information I was given.)

Comment: I use JDBC all day long. I think your question is a good one since, sometimes you want to be able to create a ODBC DSN from Java without needing to use the ODBC control panel. The reason for this is simple: the DSN may not exists yet and the JDBC port for your database might not be listening. Currently, I create DSNs from a batch file by running a .reg file. It would be nicer to do that programmatically with Java, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question is that you don't need a registered DSN.

Here is an example of using a ODBC connection (not JDBC) from Java, using the system ODBC driver.  Instead of editing the registry to create a registered DSN, your alternative is to use a un-registered DSN, like so:

```
Driver=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
Source=jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/Dir/DB/MyDB.mdb;
```

Or, using SQL Server:

```
Driver=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
Source=jdbc:odbc:Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=127.1;DATABASE=MyDB;UID=sa;PWD=mypass
```

Answer (score 2):

All ODBC configuration is in Windows registry or `odbc.ini` in Linux (I haven't used ODBC on other platforms). At first you must create such configuration using ODBC manager, then check what was saved in configuration and write program that do the same. If you work with Windows 32 bit, then check registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC`.
Windows 64 bit have different configurations for 32 bit apps and 64 bit apps (just look for `odbc.ini` string in registry).

I think Java is not the best language to change something in Windows registry, but with Java you can create `.reg` text file that can be imported by `regedit.exe`, or you can use other language like Python with win32 extensions (Active Python has it by default).

Comment: Plus points for understanding the question. Unfortunately, I think this guy is looking for a Java .jar library with support for editing DSN's  rather than a batch file solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look into using [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

Comment: I've used JDBC, but all my experience with it has either been with a MySQL or SQL database or with a database that has an ODBC connection that I have already set up using the ODBC Data Source Administrator.  Can I use it to set up that connection instead of the Data Source Administrator?

Comment: @Jessica I don't think so. I believe you have to have an ODBC Data Source setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
String driver ="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};DBQ=C:/CSVFolder

query = select * from myfile.csv
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Please provide more context, this is a code fragment out of context.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to connect to MS SQL Server before. I've always used DB2 or Derby, MYSQL and everything was always the same for creating a connection. This is what I had to do for SQL Server.

```
private final String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

Class.forName(driver);

url="jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server+","+port+";DATABASE="+dbName;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this one out..
Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) supports ODBC-based databases and provides a independent database.

```
 Connection connection = null;
     try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("connection string", "userName", "password" );
    } catch (SQLException e) {


    }   

     return connection;
```